# Audio recorder using Audio Record with playback

Tags: java, android, android-audiorecord

I want to record audio with AudioRecorder with playback(Visualization).

My playback and audio recorder well-run if I run one of them

But if I use both of them my recorded audio has very poor quality.

I found the problem

```
   bufferSize = Math.max(BUFFER_BYTES_ELEMENTS * BUFFER_BYTES_PER_ELEMENT,AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(RECORDER_SAMPLE_RATE, RECORDER_CHANNELS_IN, RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING));
   byte recordBuffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
   do {
         int bytesRead = currentAudioRecording.read(recordBuffer, 0, recordBuffer.length);
         bytesRead += 10;
         if (bytesRead > 0) {
            recordingCallback.onDataReady(recordBuffer);
         } else {
           Log.e(Recorder.class.getSimpleName(), "error: " + bytesRead);
           onRecordFailure()
           }
      } while (recorderState == RECORDER_STATE_BUSY);
```

I know thas must to change :

```
    int bytesRead = currentAudioRecording.read(recordBuffer, 0, recordBuffer.length);
```

Can anybody help me?